# Superscript text in <title></title> element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make the text in `<title></title>` superscript? If so, how?

[Meraki Baked Goods (Post 7: Dad's 50<sup>th</sup>)](https://merakibakedgoods.github.io/post07/)

Comment: This isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work for me:

```
<title>Dad's 50&#7511;&#688; Birthday</title>
```

Comment: Is there a chart with those? Like graphemica.com?

Comment: @gio I used [this website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d57/index.htm) to search for the correct codes. I hope it helps!

Comment: Cool, thanks! Now I'm wondering how I've never heard of this website.